# calculate the gradient wrt to multiple inputs using tf.gradienttape, but return none

Tags: python, tensorflow

pre-trained DNN model takes two inputs, and I want to compute gradient of output wrt two inputs

```
ta = tf.cast(input1,tf.float32) #ta in 2 dimension, tb in 3 dimension
tb = tf.cast(input2,tf.float32)
inp_tensor_list = [ta,tb]

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred = model(inp_tensor_list)  #pred return correct value here
grad = tape.gradient(pred, inp_tensor_list)
```

grad [none,none]

How to fix it? Thanks

**Solved Update**

use tf.Variable instead of tf.cast

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the variables to the `tape.gradient` call like this

`grad = tape.gradient(pred, model.trainable_variables)`

Edit:

If you want to compute the gradient wrt to a tensor, you will need explicitly ask the tape to trace the operations on the said tensor.

```py
ta = tf.cast(input1,tf.float32) #ta in 2 dimension, tb in 3 dimension
tb = tf.cast(input2,tf.float32)
inp_tensor_list = [ta,tb]

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(ta) 
    tape.watch(tb)
    pred = model(inp_tensor_list)  #pred return correct value here
grad = tape.gradient(pred, inp_tensor_list)
```

Comment: HI, thanks for you reply. the results I am expecting will have the same dimension/shape with the inputs. the above code does not produce it.